# How to login as "root user" in Altera Embedded Command Shell?

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, intel-fpga

**Hello!  I am terribly new at Linux and am struggling to login as a "root user".  My picture below shows my attempts.  What kind of user am I in now?  How do I login as a root user?**

[image]

**This is the project I'm trying to run right now:**

[image]

Comment: You are not at a Linux prompt. You are on your PC at a cygwin prompt. You probably need to use the USB cable to communicate with the board using something like putty,

Answer (score 0):

As pointed by @Richard, you need to use a tool like `putty` (if you are on Windows) and an appropriate cable to the board to communicate with the board.

Refer this : [using usb to serial converter in windows-7 with putty](http://selfmod.net/using-usb-to-serial-converter-in-windows-7-with-putty/)

You can also use `minicom` and a serial to USB cable (or appropriate cable for your board to connect it to PC USB hub), if you are using a linux machine like Ubuntu.

Once you are able to see the prompt, you will by default be logged in as `root` user.

If it asks for a login prompt, try **root** as both username and password. This may vary from vendor to vendor. Read your instruction manuals.